# How to get the newly added custom fields value in wordpress

Tags: wordpress

I have added two field using "Advance custom field" plugin. i can see the value of the custom field value in the post but problem is that how can i get that values,i have attatched the screen shot. please see the screen shot and give me some instruction that how i can get that values.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

In the backend custom field menu you was added this two fields please see that what slug is generated for that field and pass that slug in function

```
get_field('slug');
the_field('slug');
```

Reply if you understand or need more clearification..

Comment: from where i can find out the "slug"?